# Understanding of the probability using poisson

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I have a question about my statistics homework.

The question is as follows:

At an army base there are X number of soldiers hit by a car. The poisson distribution expaction of this is μ=2. The number of soldiers Y get hit by a tank has a poisson distribution of λ=1. You can assume that no one will get hit by both(a car and tank). The random variables X and Y are independent.

(I) What is P(X+Y=k) for k=0,1,2,…?

Soldier who got hit by a tank have a probability of 1/2 to die. Z is the total amount of soldiers that die because of a hit by tank.

(II)    What is P(Z=k) for k=0,1,2,…?

To Calculate the result I used the poisson formula:
$$ e^{- \lambda}  {\lambda^x\over x!}  $$

In my solution I just used the X and Y, because I do not know if X or Y ends at 2 or continuous. I assumed that it continuous because at the end of the line you will see "...".
This is my solution:

A) $$ P(x+y=k) = e^{- 2}  {2^x\over x!}  +  e^{- 1}  {1^y\over y!}$$
B) $$ P(z=k) = (e^{- 1}  {1^z\over z!}) * 1/2 $$

I'm not sure if this is the correct answer. So I hope that someone could tell me if I did something wrong.

Comment: For (A) you need to sum this over all cases where $x+y=k$.  Your (B) makes little sense as $P(Z=k)$ varies with $k$; nor it it clear why you are halving a probability rather than having the hit rate to get a death rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

(A) What is the expected number of vehicle hits per day? Does the number of vehicle hits per day have a Poisson distribution?

(B) What is the expected number of tank deaths per day? Does the number of tank deaths per day have a Poisson distribution?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think I got the answer for my first question:
\begin{align*}
   &= \frac{3^k}{k!} \cdot e^{-3}\\
\end{align*}

To be honest, I am not sure how I can solve B. I can answer your hints/questions, but I do not know how to continue from there.

Do you think my first answer is correct?

Comment: The rate of tank deaths is $\frac12$ making $P(Z=k)=\dfrac{\left(\frac12\right)^k}{k!}e^{-1/2}$